# Wicket request mapping

Tags: java, wicket

I am trying to map my requests in a special way to achieve a very simple purpose.

Say the root website is `abc.com` and has several users. Each user has a home page, admin page, requests page, etc.

Let us assume we have users `user1` and `user 2`
I want the urls to be coded as:

```
abc.com/user1/admin

abc.com/user1/home

abc.com/user1/requests
```

So basically `abc.com/user1/home` is the home page for `user 1` and `abc.com/user1/admin` is the the admin page for user 1.

I have tried using the request mapping in wicket using named parameters etc. I can encode my URL'S as `abc.com/home/user1` but I can not get the encoding I desire.
Any help is welcome.

Thanks
Anant

Comment: Can you please show in code how are you mapping these requests? If you would specify which Wicket version are you using, that could be also useful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just starting with the version 1.5 of wicket but I think the new mapping system will resolve your point quite easily :

```
mountPage("{userCode}/home", UserHomePage.class);
mountPage("{userCode}/admin", UserAdminPage.class);
```

Then, in the page you just have to retrieve the page parameter to load your model.

```
String userCode = pageParameter.get("userCode").toString();
```

Comment: I think it would be: mountPage("${userCode}/home", UserHomePage.class);